# How to Prompt the User to Login in my email sending app (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, email

I created a simple email application for Windows Phone 7, but I need to set-up my email account to send email from my application.

So Please tell me How to Prompt the User to Login in my email sending app to send email (Windows Phone 7)

This is my application code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

namespace SendingMail
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        EmailAddressChooserTask emailAddresstask;// Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.emailAddresstask = new EmailAddressChooserTask();
            this.emailAddresstask.Completed += new EventHandler<EmailResult>(emailAddresstask_Completed);
        }

        #region Events

        //Open Contact button click
        private void btnOpenContact_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            emailAddresstask.Show();
        }

        //Email Address Chooser Task Completed
        private void emailAddresstask_Completed(object sender, EmailResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                txtTo.Text = e.Email;
            }
        }

        //Send mail button click
        private void btnMail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EmailComposeTask Myemail_Composetask = new EmailComposeTask();
            Myemail_Composetask.To = txtTo.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Cc = txtCC.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Subject = txtSbj.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Body = txtbd.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Show();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do that (and you can't anyway). The operating system already prompts the user to create an email account if there isn't an email account set up on the phone.

Comment: i want to set-up my account for my email application. i don't want to use Phone settings.